# Storing large amount of images android

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-image

I'm currently creating an app that will hold several hundred images, 445 .png files to be exact, a total of 19.7MB. I'm using a recycler view and card view to display each image.

Is storing all of these images in the drawable folder the best way to do this? Also if I do store them in the drawable folder will these images be easy for people to extract from the app once it is finished? It would be nice to have a bit of security as I put quite a lot of effort into creating the images.

Comment: Extracting is easy as apple pie. Apk is just a zip archive so you can extract its content without any problems.

Comment: What would be a more secure way of doing this? @aelimill

Comment: It really depends on what kind of assets (images) are these, how crucial they are for the user/app/view. Saving them on an external server can be troublesome as well, especially that it will cost the user bandwidth to do so. If the assets are needed to be scaled on the different device types, placing them in the drawable folder would be the best (20MB is not much tho), otherwise store them in the assets folder, archived and access it in an optimized way. Also, you could use libs like Picasso to load them.

Answer (score 1):

As for me the answer is quite obvious - the best approach is to hold all needed images somewhere outside(on a server). For loading images I recommend to use Picasso - which is quite simple and has out of the box caching, you can customize it any way you want. Only two steps required - upload the images on server and request them when needed.

Answer (score 0):

It will be not easy for usual user but it can to get these images. You should encrypt files you want to protect. To built in encrypted files in apk put it into `assets` folder.

To show all images in `RecyclerView` you can load them asynchronously when user see it only. If you show thumbnails then just build these images when user launch your program at first time or while user use it and load these thumbnails all to list in next time. 

Although, for 445 images it will better to load it asynchronously. As optimization you can load some portion of images when user stopped on some item in list. For, example: List shows 5 item then you adapter must load 1 - 20 images, it takes a little bit of memory.

Comment: Would you be able to give me an example of how I could do this a asynchronously? @ghostman

Comment: [Example.](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html) Only you need change background loading on your own. And after use it in your custom adapter. Only you need to add listener to free image when `ImageView` isn't visible.

Comment: I can recommend you to create separate class `ImageBuffer` and all logic to load/free images put in it. Have your images same size?

Comment: They are all 128x128

Comment: Then you can calculate visible item count in your list. In your custom adapter `onBindViewHolder` you should call method of `ImageBuffer` and send to it ImageView and position in list, so `ImageBuffer` can understand when free old images and will load current.

Comment: Example of `ImageBuffer` method `loadImage(final int position, ImageView view)`. And constructor and setter: `ImageView(final int itemsCount /* , another args */)`, `setItemsCount(final int count)`. Setter need to support screen rotation without memory leak.